# Selected text input value while react component mounts

Tags: reactjs, primereact

I am using primereact Inputtext component and I want the initial value of it to be selected like the image[image] as I open the modal.

I know how to focus on the Inputtext using useref but it is important that the value be selected as well.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

```
<InputNumber ref={inputRef} onFocus={event => event.target.select()} />
```

after focusing on component, by using onFocus prop, the text inside it gets selected.